# ¿Cómo vuelco el mapaCalendarios ordenado en rangoCalendarios de la SpreadSheet?

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, map

Esto es un script de google app scripts. Pretendo anotar ordenados, en una hoja de cálculo de google (google SpreadSheet), todos los nombres y Id de los calendarios a los que tengo acceso.

```
function Calendarios() {
// obtiene todos los calendarios, a los que tienes acceso, y los anota ordenados, en una hoja de cálculo.
 var libroActivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var hojaCalendarios = libroActivo.getSheetByName('Calendarios');
 var rangoCalendarios = hojaCalendarios.getRange('Calendarios');
 var calendarios = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
 var calendario ={};
 var mapaCalendarios = new Map();

 rangoCalendarios.clear();

//Pongo los nombres y Id de los calendarios en un mapa
 for (calendario of calendarios) {
   mapaCalendarios.set(calendario.getName(),calendario.getId());
 };    

//Creo un iterador para el mapa, con las llaves ordenadas
 mapaCalendarios[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield* [...this.entries()].sort(function(a, b) {return a[0].localeCompare(b[0],undefined,{ caseFirst: "upper" })});
 };
**//¿Cómo vuelco el mapaCalendarios ordenado en rangoCalendarios de la SpreadSheet?**
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma básica de volcar datos en una hoja de cálculo de Google usando Google Apps Script es mediante el método `setValues(values)` de `Class Range` donde el parámetro values es un objeto de tipo Array bidimiensional.

Si cuentas on objeto de tipo Map deberas convertirlo a un Array bidimensional, para lo cual podrías usar [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from)

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén, probaré a ver que tal me vá.